# How do I install stream-m on my vps server using putty for windows

Tags: jar, ffmpeg, video-streaming, putty, vps

when i logged into my vps server using the plesk control panel i see httpdocs in the root when using putty i entered an ls command and i only see

@vps:~# ls
ffmpeg  parallels  parallels_installer  plesk-installer.sh  univac.webm

wonder why this is why dont i see the same files as in te control panel??!

the problem is i am trying to run this https://github.com/vbence/stream-m on the server 
the read me says

RUNNING THE SERVER

java -jar stream-m.jar

Before running the server you should edit the sample config file (change password and choose a stream name). So you will end up with something like:

java -jar stream-m.jar server.properties

but im getting an error that says

@vps:~# java -jar stream-m.jar server.properties
Error: Unable to access jarfile stream-m.jar

Now i do have ffmpeg installed as per putty but when logged into the control panel i don't see that either what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are trying to run the sources, not the compiled package.
You can download the zip archive, which contains the Stream-m.jar from [THIS](https://github.com/vbence/stream-m/releases) link.